# Using Python CGI for a big HTML file

Tags: python, html, web, cgi

I have a big html file named exercise.html, I need generate to one  som stuff by Python CGI.
I want to ask you what is the best way to print this HTML.

I know that it is possible by print method with using format methods %s, %i etc.:

```
print '''<html>
<head><title>My first Python CGI app</title></head>
<body> 
<p>Hello, 'world'!</p>
.
.
<div>%s</div>
.
.
</body>
</html>''' % generated_text
```

But this HTML is really big,so is this only one solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using a templating language like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/#basic-api-usage).

Here is a simple example straight from the link above:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> template = Template('Hello {{ name }}!')
>>> template.render(name='John Doe')
```

Generally, though you save templates in a file, and then load / process them:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
# The env object below finds templates that are lcated in the `templates`
# directory of your `yourapplication` package.
env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('yourapplication', 'templates'))
template = env.get_template('mytemplate.html')
print template.render(the='variables', go='here')
```

As demonstrated above, templates let you put `variables` into the template.  Placing text inside {{ }} makes it a template variable.  When you render the template, pass in the variable value with a keyword argument.  For instance, the template below has a name variable that we pass via template.render

> This is my {{name}}.

```
template.render(name='Jaime')
```

Answer (score 1):

Also consider [Python Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) ([SimpleTemplate Engine](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html)).  It is worth noting that bottle.py supports mako, jinja2 and cheetah templates.

The % indicates python code and the {{var}} are the substitution variables

HTML:

```
<ul>
  % for item in basket:
  <li>{{item}}</li>
  % end
</ul>
```

Python:

```
with open('index.html', 'r') as htmlFile:
    return bottle.template(htmlFile.read(), basket=['item1', 'item2'])
```